# python scrapy - get specific @href, when href contains specific string

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy, href, contains

My end goal is to get the last part of the `href` i.e. company name or brand name.

Using the below examples, how can I grab the `href` that contains the `string` 'brand' for example, or 'business'?

```
<a class="nocolorchange" href="/guides/brand/6429-ArmHammer">
<a class="nocolorchange" href="/guides/business/5928-ChurchDwightCoInc">
```

I have tried:

```
//a[matches(@href, 'business')] # or brand
```

with no luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First, I don't know if you are using `scrapy shell` but it can be useful to test those kind of things.

As `matches` is only available in XPath 2.0 you can try with:

```
//a[starts-with(@href, '/guides/business/')]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
hrefs_xpath="//a/@href[contains(., 'business') or contains(.,'brand')]"

# with scrapy, you extract this xpath pattern
hrefs=response.xpath(hrefs_xpath).extract()

# then extract company names
companies=[href.rpartition('/')[-1] for href in hrefs]
```